# Adding ImageSpan after Html.fromHtml();

Tags: android, html, spannable

I have an JSON String which contains HTML Tags and image like this one:

```
<center>denn.. <span class="uicon" style="background-image:url(http://static.allmystery.de/images/lachen.gif);width:15px;height:14px;" title=":)">:)</span>
ich habe immer versucht ein <small>perfektionist</small> zu sein ohne das es mir klar war.<br><br>
```

I tried to replace the smileys with 
img src= ""
tags but its a pain to load them with an ImageGetter.I was successful with Picasso and ImageSpans. My Question is, it is possible to add Imagespans after I used HTML.fromHtml(String)?

I want to display everything in an EditText if it matters.

EDIT:

If someone has the same trouble of displaying images in EditText or TextViews here is my solution to this annoying problem:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(text));

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ADD REGEX TO FIND IMAGE URLS);
Matcher m = p.matcher(spannableString);

        while (m.find()) {

            //m.start() will give you the startlocation of the matched string
            //m.end() does the same with the endlocation
            //m.group(1) contains the imageurl which is captured with regex

            //CustomTarget implements Target from Picasso (Imageloading library)
            //holder.postText is the EditText or TextView

            CustomTarget target = new CustomTarget(m.group(1), m.start(), m.end(), holder.postText, spannableString);

            //add target to an ArrayList to keep a strong reference to prevent that the target gets garbage collected
            // before the image is placed into the view
            targets.add(target);

            //load the image into the CustomTarget
            Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
            picasso.setDebugging(true);
            picasso.load(m.group(1)).into(target);
        }
```

CustomTarget Class:

```
   private class CustomTarget implements Target {

    String url;
    int start;
    int end;
    WeakReference<EditText> postText;
    SpannableString rawText;


    public CustomTarget(String url, int start, int end, EditText postText, SpannableString rawText) {

        this.url = url;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.postText = new WeakReference<>(postText);
        this.rawText = rawText;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

        //get a weak Reference to the EditText because holder pattern in ListView will replace the View inside the holder before the Async Task is done
        EditText editText = postText.get();

        //Get existing ImageSpans to add them later again, if not, you will only get the last loaded image displayed
        ImageSpan[] spans =  editText.getText().getSpans(0, editText.length(), ImageSpan.class);

        BitmapDrawable d =  new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth()+5, d.getIntrinsicHeight()+5);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan( d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

        //add ImageSpan to the SpannableString
        rawText.setSpan(imageSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        //add previously added ImageSpans
        if (spans.length >= 1) {

            for (ImageSpan image: spans) {


                rawText.setSpan(image, editText.getText().getSpanStart(image), editText.getText().getSpanEnd(image), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            }

        }
        //add the edited SpannableString to the EditText
        editText.setText(rawText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        //remove target from ArrayList to allow Garbage Collection
        targets.remove(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

NOTE: you should do some resizing if your images are larger

How it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCuxU.png

Comment: what's targets in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add spans, you need a [`Spannable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) instance. However, `Html.fromHtml()` returns a [`Spanned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) object, which doesn't provide for this.

> This is the interface for text that has markup objects attached to
>   ranges of it. Not all text classes have mutable markup or text; see
>   Spannable for mutable markup and Editable for mutable text.

However, you can create a `Spannable` from a `Spanned`, pretty easily. Just use:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("..."));
```

Comment: After endless hours of pain with ImageGetter just to display images in an TextView or EditText this was the solution. Thank you, I able to die happy now.

Comment: @notsure You're welcome. Make sure that doesn't happen too soon. ;)